# How to get the row/line count of constraint layout's flow helper?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I have 3 views that i included in flow helper of constraint layout and are laid out like this:

|TextView1| |View(delimeter)| |TextView2|

when text of TextView2 doesn't fit it moves to next line:

|TextView1| |View(delimeter)|

|TextView2|

the problem here is that when TextView2 moves to next line i need to remove or make View(delimeter) visibility as gone, and to do so i need a way to know if flow layout has more than one row.

i checked for built in functions inside flow but none existing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.